# Sometimes my screen goes blank in Meteor but there are no errors

Tags: meteor

I have a simple meteor build here https://github.com/MARS1/meteorTest

My problem is that there are no errors yet when I go to my local host I get a blank page and no clue as to why the app is not rendering.

I know this is a pretty basic question and I often find that most people don't get hung up on questions like this one but for some reason I do:)

Any help would be greatly appreciated I think anyone that has used Meteor for a few months would probably be able to solve in minutes.

Here are my routes:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'appLayout',
    yieldTemplates: {  //updated per comment
        header: {to: 'header'},
        home: {to: 'home'},
        footer: {to: 'footer'}
    }
});


Router.route('/' , {
    name: "home"
});
```

Here is my template:

```
<template name="home">
    <h1>Hello World this is the Home page</h1>

</template>
```

Here is my main layout:

```
<head>
    <title>Static title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<template name="appLayout">

    {{> header}}

    <div class="container">

        {{> yield}}

    </div>



    {{> footer}}

</template>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo in your `Router.configure`: it should be `yieldTemplates` not `yieldTemplate`

Comment: Please try to isolate the issue and post the relevant code here. If the repository dies or changes, your question loses most of its meaning.

Comment: @Kyll I've included it in the example now. Thanks.

Comment: @BraveKenny not sure where i'm going wrong but I've updated to "yieldTemplates" but the template still doesn't render